# Define a real number by stringing together all positive integers in order $0.123456789101112131415...$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, constants

The question is is this number irrational?

I know that an irrational number cannot be written as the quotient of two integers. The only way I can think to begin this problem is to assume to the contrary that that number can be written as $\frac{m}{n}$

Still, I don't know how to show this using math or even where to begin. Ideas?

Comment: Check out [Champernowne's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).

Answer (score 2):

It is irrational, because there is no repeating block.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that number, let's call it $\alpha$, were rational with $\alpha=\frac{n}{m}$. Let $k\geq 0$ be a nonnegative integer with $10^k>m$. Then at some point the digits of $\alpha$ look like
$$
\alpha=0.12345\cdots 999\underbrace{1000\cdots00}_{10^k}100\cdots
$$
Multiplying by the right power of $10$ gives
$$
10^a\alpha=
12345\cdots 9991\,.\,\underbrace{000\cdots00}_{k\text{ zeros}}100\cdots
$$
and so $0<10^a\alpha-12345\cdots 9991< \frac2{10^{k+1}}<\frac1{10^{k}}$. Multiplying this by $m$ gives
$$
0<\underbrace{\overbrace{m10^a\alpha}^{=10^an} - m\times 12345\cdots 9991}_{\in\Bbb{N}} = m\times(10^a\alpha-12345\cdots 9991)<\frac{m}{10^{k}}<1
$$
This is a contradiction and so $\alpha$ is irrational.